# Implementing a temporary data context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-system

I implemented a [context manager](https://gitlab.com/HOMEINFO/tempfileplus/blob/master/tempfileplus.py) to handle temporary files and directories.

```
"""Temporary data management."""

from contextlib import ExitStack
from tempfile import template, NamedTemporaryFile, TemporaryDirectory


__all__ = ['TemporaryDataContext']


class TemporaryDataContext(ExitStack):
    """A context manager for temporary files and folders."""

    def __init__(self, root=None, prefix=template):
        """Initializes the context manager with an
        optional temporary data root and prefix.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.root = root
        self.prefix = prefix

    def mktemp(self, mode='w+b', encoding=None, suffix=''):
        """Creates and registers a named temporary
        file and returns the file object.
        """
        temp = self.enter_context(NamedTemporaryFile(
            suffix=suffix, prefix=self.prefix, dir=self.root))
        temp.file.close()
        return open(temp.name, mode=mode, encoding=encoding)

    def mkdtemp(self, suffix=''):
        """Creates and registers a temporary
        directory and returns its path.
        """
        return self.enter_context(TemporaryDirectory(
            suffix=suffix, prefix=self.prefix, dir=self.root))
```

It is being invoked by a data processing API to arbitrarily create temporary files and directories, that need to survive the entire processing chain and will be cleaned up at the end.

I am especially interested in optimizing the `mktemp` method, which seems awkward to me (though it does its job).

Comment: IMO your update would be better as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized, that I can simplify `mktemp` by directly returning the `tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper`'s buffer, which can be used in a file context for open and closing without deleting the superordinate `_TemporaryFileWrapper`:

```
def mktemp(self, mode='w+b', encoding=None, suffix=''):
    """Creates and registers a named temporary
    file and returns the file object.
    """
    return self.enter_context(NamedTemporaryFile(
        mode=mode, encoding=encoding, suffix=suffix, prefix=self.prefix,
        dir=self.root)).file
```

**Update**
With the change above, the returned buffer does not behave as expected regarding its attribute `name`.
To fix that, I introduced a wrapper class:

```
class NamedFile:
    """Wraps a file buffer and its associated name."""

    def __init__(self, file, name):
        """Sets buffer and name."""
        self.file = file
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        return self.file.__exit__(typ, value, traceback)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.file, attr)

    @classmethod
    def from_ntf(cls, named_temporary_file):
        """Creates a named file from the specified NamedTemporaryFile."""
        return cls(named_temporary_file.file, named_temporary_file.name)
```

And return it instead of the raw buffer accordingly:

```
def mktemp(self, mode='w+b', encoding=None, suffix=''):
    """Creates and registers a named temporary
    file and returns the file object.
    """
    return NamedFile.from_ntf(self.enter_context(NamedTemporaryFile(
        mode=mode, encoding=encoding, suffix=suffix, prefix=self.prefix,
        dir=self.root)))
```